# Pig script getting hang at group by statement

Tags: apache-pig, amazon-emr

pig script that I have written is running on my local on 4gb of data but when I try ti run it on EMR cluster it is getting hang at a particular group by statement.Below is the error that I am getting...

```
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$NoOpVertexManager.onVertexStateUpdated(VertexImpl.java:4528)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexManager$VertexManagerEventOnVertexStateUpdate.invoke(VertexManager.java:564)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexManager$VertexManagerEvent$1.run(VertexManager.java:647)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexManager$VertexManagerEvent$1.run(VertexManager.java:642)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexManager$VertexManagerEvent.call(VertexManager.java:642)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexManager$VertexManagerEvent.call(VertexManager.java:631)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Caused by: org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.AMUserCodeException: Fail to initialize Edge,EdgeInfo: sourceVertexName=scope-325, destinationVertexName=scope-329
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.Edge.initialize(Edge.java:174)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.Edge.setEdgeProperty(Edge.java:196)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.setParallelismWrapper(VertexImpl.java:1724)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:133)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.library.vertexmanager.ShuffleVertexManager$CustomShuffleEdgeManager.initialize(ShuffleVertexManager.java:251)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.Edge.initialize(Edge.java:171)
        ... 18 more
]
Vertex killed, vertexName=scope-346, vertexId=vertex_1509345097826_0006_1_11, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill in NEW state., Vertex vertex_1509345097826_0006_1_11 [scope-346] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]
Vertex killed, vertexName=scope-344, vertexId=vertex_1509345097826_0006_1_10, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill in NEW state., Vertex vertex_1509345097826_0006_1_10 [scope-344] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]
Vertex killed, vertexName=scope-334, vertexId=vertex_1509345097826_0006_1_09, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill in INITED state., Vertex vertex_1509345097826_0006_1_09 [scope-334] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]
Vertex killed, vertexName=scope-317, vertexId=vertex_1509345097826_0006_1_02, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill in INITED state., Vertex vertex_1509345097826_0006_1_02 [scope-317] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]
Vertex killed, vertexName=scope-316, vertexId=vertex_1509345097826_0006_1_01, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill while in RUNNING state., Vertex did not succeed due to OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE, failedTasks:0 killedTasks:1, Vertex vertex_1509345097826_0006_1_01 [scope-316] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]
Vertex killed, vertexName=scope-315, vertexId=vertex_1509345097826_0006_1_00, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill while in RUNNING state., Vertex did not succeed due to OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE, failedTasks:0 killedTasks:68, Vertex vertex_1509345097826_0006_1_00 [scope-315] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]
DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:6 killedVertices:6

Answer (score 0):

What pig code you are running ? provide complete information along with data and complete pig code ?